# I accidentally deleted all the logins in my SQL DB, now I am unable to connect

Tags: sql-server-2008, authentication

Is there anyway to get in the server and recreate them?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how on earth did you do that?

Comment: eKek - how will he backup the databases since that requires access to the server?

Comment: after i will get the solution will tell you....
how i did that??
it's the same question like "how did you get married!?"
common answer: $hit happens

Comment: ROFL!!  I love the comparison to getting married...

Comment: BTW : Thanks for selecting my answer as "the answer."  It should work out just fine for you.

Comment: I had to reinstall the entire OS!!!
For some reason I was unable to uninstall SQL server :(
Thanks god, I am finally done! look how many hours it took me!

Comment: I have the same issue - deleted my own windows login from the SQL Server logins.  So far I have tried doing a repair only - no change.  Now doing uninstall then reinstall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to reinstall the server as there is no "grip" available to run anything to restore the accounts or create new ones.

Since you can't backup your databases either (again, no way to get there from here) you'll want to stop the SQL Server service (MSSQLSERVER) in the Services panel so that it releases its exclusive lock on your database files.  Next, navigate to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data and copy all of the MDF and LDF files to a safe spot.

Next, uninstall and re-install SQL Server (you *may* be able to just reinstall).  Once you are up and running again, copy the MDF/LDF files back (NOT the model, msdb or master databases!!  Just the ones that YOU have created) and "attach" them in a SQL window.  You'll do all of this with the Windows integrated account.

Comment: Shimmy - I don't think so but, honestly, I wouldn't trust it. In fact, it is likely that system restore will be more trouble than the solution provided!  Once you do it, I think you'll find it is pretty straightforward.

Comment: I think it should work and even trustable.
In my particular nutcase, as I said above, I had to resinstall the entire OS.

Comment: Good luck shimmy...I didn't realize that you had to reinstall the entire OS.

Answer (score 6):

I actually found a much simpler solution to this here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/raulga/archive/2007/07/12/disaster-recovery-what-to-do-when-the-sa-account-password-is-lost-in-sql-server-2005.aspx

The short version (in case that link dies) is that if you restart the sql server in single user mode "net start mssqlserver /m" then a member of the local machine's administrator group will be able to connect with windows authentication.  You can then change the sa password, add new accounts, or whatever you need.

Comment: Brilliant. Worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Does the surface area configuration tool still work?  If so you could attempt to use that to add another admin to the instance.